# Embed executable Blazor code into a JSON input string

Tags: html, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following Blazor code where data values are input from a JSON file.

```
<p>@product.Name</p>
<p>@((MarkupString)product.Description)</p>
```

What I would like to do is embed @product.Name into the Description text in the JSON file so it is rendered as part of the description.
I am looking for something simple like this:

```
"Description": "This a detailed description of the <dummytag>@product.Name</dummytag> product or service".
```

I've tried various combinations but have not been able to render gen3Product.Name.
Can anyone tell me how to do this, please.
I know this can lead to bad security outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blazor, `@product.Name` has to be compile prior to deployment. So embedding this in your data won't work.

You can however use old style string formatting:

```
 "Description": "This a detailed description of the <dummytag>{0}</dummytag> product or service"
```

and then

```
 <p>@((MarkupString) string.Format(product.Description, product.Name)</p>
```

but this is obviously less flexible.